# Would a class loaded with an extension override a plain PHP Composer fallback?

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

Let's say we have a class implemented in a PHP extension called `My\Example\Object`. To allow for graceful degredation, I would like to provide a standard PHP implementation for the same class, also as `My\Example\Object`. If the extension is loaded, would it use the extension one instead of the PHP class? Assume that we're using the Composer autoloader if that makes any difference.

So, with the extension loaded, would the following use the `.php` file at all?

```
<?php

use My\Example\Object;

new Object();
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. I figured it'd take someone 2 minutes to submit an answer and allow someone else with the same question in the future to find the answer for themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does.

The namespace from the extension will be resolved first.